# Python not finding its Packages

Tags: python, bash, pip, virtualenv

I wrote myself a handy bash script, which solves the task of creating a `virtualenv` with its own compiled virtualenv and python. It aims at creating a mostly self contained virtualenv, with maybe only native libraries installed in system level if necessary, but installing all python packages and virtualenv and pip and such things inside the virtualenv.

The script can be found [here](https://github.com/ZelphirKaltstahl/bash-scripts/blob/master/self_contained_venv.sh).

I invoke the script as follows:

```
self_contained_venv.sh \
-n udacity_model_building_and_validation \
-p https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.4/Python-3.4.4.tar.xz \
-v https://pypi.python.org/packages/c8/82/7c1eb879dea5725fae239070b48187de74a8eb06b63d9087cd0a60436353/virtualenv-15.0.1.tar.gz#md5=28d76a0d9cbd5dc42046dd14e76a6ecc \
-d pandas scikit-learn seaborn
```

Given the required packages for compiling python and virtualenv are installed on the system, the script creates a nice virtualenv. However, when I try to access any installed modules/packages from within the virtualenv, python is not able to find them. To demonstrate this, I'll put some output of commands and code here:

First of all of course I have to activate the virtualenv:

```
. bin/activate
```

**output**: None, works without problem.

Then I print the pythonpath python is aware of:

```
import sys
for i in sys.path:
    print(i)
```

**output**:

```
/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/lib/python34.zip
/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/lib/python3.4
/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/lib/python3.4/plat-linux
/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload
/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/localpython/lib/python3.4
/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/localpython/lib/python3.4/plat-linux
/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

So far so good. Then I try to import a module / package I installed during usage of my bash script: `pandas`:

```
python
```

(IDLE is running)

```
import pandas as pd
```

**output**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Another try:

```
import numpy as np
```

**output**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Huh? So none of the packages is available? Lets check pip again:

```
which pip
```

**output**:

```
alias pip='localpython/bin/pip3.4'
./localpython/bin/pip3.4
```

Ok, so it's using my local pip.

Check packages:

```
pip list
```

**output**:

```
numpy (1.11.0)
pandas (0.18.1)
pip (8.1.2)
psutil (4.1.0)
Python-contrib-nbextensions (alpha)
python-dateutil (2.5.3)
pytz (2016.4)
PyYAML (3.11)
setuptools (18.2)
six (1.10.0)
virtualenv (15.0.1)
```

Hm the packages are there, so why can't python find them? Let's see where those packages are located, simply by trying to remove one:

```
pip uninstall pandas
```

**output** (shortened, because it fills many pages):

```
Uninstalling pandas-0.18.1:
 /home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/localpython/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas-0.18.1-py3.4.egg-info
  /home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/localpython/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py
  /home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/localpython/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc
  /home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/localpython/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/__pycache__/_version.cpython-34.pyc
  /home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/localpython/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/__pycache__/info.cpython-34.pyc
```

Aha, so the packages *are* in the path.

Another attempt on finding out if python looks in the right places:

```
>>> from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
>>> print(get_python_lib())
/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

So this one indicates it does not look in the right place, if I understand correctly.

**Note**:

The script does the following things, which might not be obvious:

- compile python with a prefix (local python)
- compile virtualenv for the local python
- it aliases pip to the local pip of the version of the installed python
- it aliases virtualenv to the locally installed one
- it installs packages from pypi if specified
- it updates the local pip if there is a newer version available

I am a beginner still at writing bash scripts, so I think the structure and logic of the script is fairly easy to understand. It also prints information about success of its operations in the terminal.

---

**Further Notes**:

- I did not use `su` or `sudo` to run the script.
- My OS is a Fedora 22, although I think in this case any major distro would work the same way.
- OS has been updated recently.

**Question**: So why can't Python find them / its own packages? (What do I need to change?)

Comment: Why are you compiling python from source? Why not use the fedora package?

Comment: @hd1 This is supposed to be a self contained virtualenv. I have python on my system as well as the anaconda distribution, but that's not the point of this script. The virtualenv shall have its own python interpreter, its own packages etc, not relying on system packages. I'll add some info about this to the question.

Comment: first line from pip uninstall output: `/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/localpython/lib/python3.4/site-packages/s` isn't in your sys.path - only site-packages dir in your sys.path is `/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_model_building_and_validation/lib/python3.4/site-packages` which misses `localpython` directory

Answer (score 0):

can you try to compare path to pyhton and pip in your script and manually in your system:
`which python` and `which pip`?
After that check `pip freeze | grep pandas` it should return you package ...if no you need to add this package to site-packages folder of you python.